# How to lower LCP time for this component?

Tags: reactjs, performance, deployment, pagespeed

I have a React component, named ImageSlider, to create a dynamic image slideshow with swipe gesture support and manual navigation controls. I'm using it in an Astro web application. Here's a detailed breakdown of its structure and functionality:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BsChevronCompactLeft, BsChevronCompactRight } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { RxDotFilled } from 'react-icons/rx';

type ImageSliderProps = {
    images: String[]; // String of URLs served on ImageKit.io
};

export function ImageSlider({ images }: ImageSliderProps) {
    const [currentImageIndex, setCurrentImageIndex] = useState(0);
    let xdelta = null;
    let ydelta = null;

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            const isLastImage = currentImageIndex === images.length - 1;
            const newIndex = isLastImage ? 0 : currentImageIndex + 1;
            setCurrentImageIndex(newIndex);
        }, 5000);

        return () => clearInterval(interval); // cleanup
    }, [currentImageIndex, images.length]);

    const handleTouchStart = (e) => {
        xdelta = e.touches[0].clientX;
        ydelta = e.touches[0].clientY;
    }

    const handleTouchEnd = (e) => {
        const xmove = xdelta !== null ? e.changedTouches[0].clientX - xdelta : 0;
        const ymove = ydelta !== null ? e.changedTouches[0].clientY - ydelta : 0;
        if (Math.abs(xmove) > Math.abs(ymove)) {
            if (xmove > 0) {
                handlePreviousImage();
            } else {
                handleNextImage();
            }
        }
    }

    const handleNextImage = () => {
        const isLastImage = currentImageIndex === images.length - 1;
        const newIndex = isLastImage ? 0 : currentImageIndex + 1;
        setCurrentImageIndex(newIndex);
    };

    const handlePreviousImage = () => {
        const isFirstImage = currentImageIndex === 0;
        const newIndex = isFirstImage ? images.length - 1 : currentImageIndex - 1;
        setCurrentImageIndex(newIndex);
    };

    const goToImage = (index: number) => {
        setCurrentImageIndex(index);
    }

    return (
        <div className='max-w-[1400px]  w-full m-auto py-4 px-4 relative group'>
            <div
                onTouchStart={handleTouchStart}
                onTouchEnd={handleTouchEnd}
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${images[currentImageIndex]})` }}
                className='w-full h-64 sm:h-96 md:h-[70vh] lg:h-[80vh] xl:h-[90vh] bg-center bg-contain bg-no-repeat duration-1000'
            ></div>
            <div className='absolute top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 left-5 text-2xl rounded-full p-2 bg-black/20 text-white cursor-pointer'>
                <BsChevronCompactLeft onClick={handlePreviousImage} />
            </div>
            <div className='absolute top-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 right-5 text-2xl rounded-full p-2 bg-black/20 text-white cursor-pointer'>
                <BsChevronCompactRight onClick={handleNextImage} />
            </div>
            <div className='flex top-4 justify-center py-2'>
                {images.map((_image, index) => (
                    <div
                        key={index}
                        onClick={() => goToImage(index)}
                        className='text-2xl cursor-pointer'
                    >
                        <RxDotFilled className={index === currentImageIndex ? 'text-black' : 'text-black/50'} />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This component is resulting in a low PageSpeed performance score. How do I improve it?

Comment: More info would be helpful. Can you share a Lighthouse test (or use PageSpeed Insights if the site is public)? Are you using SSR? What's the LCP time you're seeing? Does the LCP time increase each time the slider auto-advances?